# What kind of appearance does 丰泽的肌肤 have？

Tags: meaning-in-context

“宝钗生得肌肤丰泽，宝玉看着她雪白的胳膊，不觉动了羡慕之心。”

'丰泽的肌肤' looks like what?? Maybe just like her 雪白的胳膊??

> Edit
>     Thanks for the answers. So if we slip into a Yorkshire brogue:
>
> 宝钗生得肌肤丰泽， Bao Chai 'ad become a buxom lass wi' a radiant complexion,

Answer (score 3):

'丰' in '丰泽' means '丰滿' (plump/ full) or '丰富'(rich)

'泽' in '丰泽' means '润泽 (moist) or 光泽' (Shiny)

I would say '肌肤丰泽' means '肌肤丰滿而有光泽' (full body with shiny skin)

宝钗 is a healthy looking lady with shiny skin, while 林黛玉 is a thin and pale girl

*'full' here doesn't mean 'fat', it means ' plump and bouncy' (丰满而有弹性)*

Answer (score 2):

丰: 充满

泽: 润泽，湿润，光泽

丰泽 can mean 湿润充满光泽 in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

“丰泽的皮肤” in English might be "resilient and glossy skin", usually describe female.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I would use 'resilient', which basically means 'tough, not easily deformed, see: resilience: re = again + salire = jump together means 'resists deformation.' Unless of course, she is one tough lady!

Comment: @Pedroski, yeah, understood you. I am not an English Language expert, not sure which word is the best one. But seems you also understand my meaning. How about "elastic" or "flexible" or something else for describing this idea?